# SKAction runs fast every time i run it

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, duration, skaction

I have a problem in my Sprite kit game project, whenever i run SKAction in my game it increase the speed of SKAction like:-

```
SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveToX:enemy.position.x duration:1];
[_player runAction: moveAction];
```

When ever this action runs, it runs perfect on first time, but after that it runs fast, and it looks like that it decrease the duration every time it runs.
And this is happening with all SKAction i used in my game.

I've already searched for this issue on other sits, but cant find anything relate to my problem.

Thank you for sharing your knowledge and time.

Comment: are you per chance running the same action twice on the same node?

Comment: Yes i am running this same action multiple times on same node.

Comment: That there is the problem. Where are you calling this action? In the update method?

Comment: No i am not using skaction in update method.I am using this action in touchBegain method, and every time i call this method it start moving fast.

Comment: Use runAction:withKey instead and only run the action on the node after the old action is done.

Comment: 0x141E Your words "only run the action on the node after the old action is done. ". How do i do that i am using this action in repeatForever action.

Comment: The code you posted does not repeat forever

Comment: You'r right, but i am talking about other SKAction methods that i am using in my classes, i am continuously repeating the action using repeat forever action.